# how to run flash player videos on chromedriver on ubuntu?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, flash

I have installed chromedriver on ubuntu. Now I execute the chromedriver with following command:

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")

And then I try to run a link with [hls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) video.
But I get an error saying "Please installl Flash Player" and the video never runs.
Can somebody help me figure out.

Note: the same video works on my default Chrome browser on the same system.

Answer (score 1):

The sites that don't work probably use the adobe flashplugin. Chromium needs a different flash plugin than Firefox uses to view flash media. My guess is that you don't have it installed. So,

Run the "Software and Updates" package, and on the "other software" tab, check "Canonical Partners". See the attached screenshot. Close, and reload the software lists.

Then install the package adobe-flashplugin.

If you had installed "flashplugin-installer", it will be removed, but that is ok since adobe-flashplugin will also supply the flashplugin for firefox.